# Java String.split("\\s+")

Tags: java, string, token

I am trying to parse some output. The output is as follows:

`raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0`

My code is as follows:

```
String line = "\traidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0";
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
```

tokens ends up being `{"raidz1-0", "ONLINE", "0"}`

For some reason the last 2 zeros are discarded. I would like to retain the zeros, please tell me how.

Comment: Are you quite sure that this is what actually happens?

Comment: Please include the code which determines what tokens were split - you may be doing something wrong there.

Comment: I am watching the values in a debugger. Also noted I missed a tab in the source string, check out my edited OP

Comment: Even that would not make a difference. With tab also, you will get the last 3 zeros. Please post surrounding code.

Comment: Could you add `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));` immediately after the `split()`, and post the result.

Comment: How are you retrieving tokens from your array?

Comment: You wouldn't by any chance be adding these tokens into a `Set`, would you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it works fine in my case, and it should work: -

```
String line = "\traidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0";
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[, raidz1-0, ONLINE, 0, 0, 0]
```

Are you sure, you didn't get the last two zeros?

Comment: Thanks you are right, it is how I was looking at the debugger. Your verification did indeed help, thanks!

Comment: Worked all along, the IDE threw me off.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
String line = "\traidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0";
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(tokens.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

prints:

```
    6
    [, raidz1-0, ONLINE, 0, 0, 0]
```